What is the difference between Oracle Virtualbox and Oracle VM VirtualBox?
oracle.com offers a download at time of writing of Oracle VM VirtualBox 7.0.22, while virtualbox.org offers Oracle Virtualbox 7.1.4.
Are these the same product with different forks (the way OpenOffice and LibreOffice are), or are they categorically different? Is one any more trustworthy? Are they cross-compatible?
I have generally run the Oracle VM VirtualBox, having no idea the virtualbox.org application existed, the similarity but difference, with the oracle logo also on this site, feels like the .org version might not be legitimate.

It’s the same application, evident by the fact, the files are hosted on virtualbox.org. The oracle website just hasn’t been updated

Virtualbox.org was and still is the original Virtualbox website.
This version is still open source and free.
Oracle acquired Virtualbox (and MySql) as part of their take-over of Sun Microsystems a few years ago.
In true Oracle fashion they immediately started monetizing VirtualBox by creating their own paid-for support program. The Oracle VM version ties into that, but is nothing more than a rebrand of a slightly older version VirtualBox.
The industry-expectation (based on Oracles past behavior) is that Oracle at some point will make their Oracle VM slightly different and, when sufficient vendor-lockin is achieved, will start asking money for it.
(They are doing the same thing with MySql, which lead to the MySql community forking MariaDB.)

It is literally the same product. It was rebranded in May 2024 (with a new logo and all), but was available at the same virtualbox.org website for many years before that.

I've just come in at the time when the logo, the site, and even the available version are all different, giving the impression of a fork or clone.
